# scrollable canvas working with .pack but not .place

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, customtkinter

I am trying to get my scrollable canvas to work. It works when I pack the elements using .pack, however when I insert the elements via .place, the scrollbar stops working. Here is a minimal reproducable example of my code.

`startup.py` file:

```
import frame as f
import placeWidgetsOnFrame as p

p.populate3()
f.window.mainloop()
```

`frame.py` file:

```
#Creates widnow
window = customtkinter.CTk()
window.geometry("1900x980")
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
window.resizable(False, False)

#Creates Frame for GUI
mainFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(window, width=1900, height=980, corner_radius=0)
mainFrame.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
mainFrame.pack_propagate(False)

topFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=mainFrame, width=1865, height=140, corner_radius=10)
topFrame.grid(columnspan=2, padx=15, pady=15)
topFrame.pack_propagate(0)

leftFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=mainFrame, width=380, height=530, corner_radius=10)
leftFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=15, pady=10)
leftFrame.pack_propagate(False)

rightFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=mainFrame, width=1450, height=775, corner_radius=10)
rightFrame.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=15, pady=10, rowspan=2)
rightFrame.pack_propagate(False)

bottomLeftFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(mainFrame, width=380, height=220, corner_radius=10)
bottomLeftFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=15, pady=10)
bottomLeftFrame.pack_propagate(False)

#Creates Scrollbar for right Frame

#Creates a canvas for the right Frame
canvas2=tk.Canvas(rightFrame, bg="#000000", highlightthickness=0, relief="flat")
canvas2.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

#Creates a scroll bar for the right Frame
scrollbar = customtkinter.CTkScrollbar(master=rightFrame, orientation="vertical", command=canvas2.yview, corner_radius=10)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

#Configures scrollbar to canvas
canvas2.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
canvas2.bind("<Configure>", lambda *args, **kwargs: canvas2.configure(scrollregion=canvas2.bbox("all")))

#Creates a scrollable frame to place widgets on
scrollableFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(canvas2, fg_color=("#C0C2C5", "#343638"), corner_radius=10)
canvasFrame = canvas2.create_window((0,0), window=scrollableFrame, anchor="nw", tags=("cf"))

#TO DO - resize canvas and to fit all widgets
def handleResize(event):
    c = event.widget
    cFrame = c.nametowidget(c.itemcget("cf", "window"))
    minWidth = cFrame.winfo_reqwidth()
    minHeight = cFrame.winfo_reqheight()
    print (event.width)
    print (event.height)
    if minWidth < event.width:
        c.itemconfigure("cf", width=event.width)
    if minHeight < event.height:
        c.itemconfigure("cf", height=event.height)
    print (event.width)
    print (event.height)
    c.configure(scrollregion=c.bbox("all"))

canvas2.bind('<Configure>', handleResize)

def onMousewheel(event):
    canvas2.yview_scroll(-1 * round(event.delta / 120), "units")


canvas2.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", onMousewheel)    
canvas2.bind("<Destroy>", lambda *args, **kwargs: canvas2.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>"))
```

`placeWidgetsOnFrame.py` file:

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter
import frame as f
rightFrame = f.scrollableFrame
def populate2():
    for i in range(30):
        emailLabel = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=rightFrame, text="Please enter your email:")
        emailLabel.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        

def populate3():
    x=50
    for i in range(30):
        emailLabel = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=rightFrame, text="Please enter your email:")
        emailLabel.place(x=40, y=x)
        x=x+50
```

Here is the output when `populate3()` is run:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9bcJ.png)

Here is the output when `populate2()` is run
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3uBi.png)

Does anyone know why this is? I can always go back and change the way I insert widgets to `.pack` rather than `.place`, however I would rather use `.place` as I find it easier to place widgets where I want to.

Comment: _"it doesn't work."_ - could you be a bit more descriptive, please? What does "doesn't work" mean? Does the program crash? Do you get an error? Does the scrolling scroll in the wrong direction? ...

Comment: ***I would rather use .place as I find it easier to place widgets where I want to.*** That is not really accurate. Once you learn how `grid()` and `pack()` work it is much easier to manage your GUI with them. Also from the standpoint of maintainability `place()` is terrible. Many new Python devs (Including myself) tend to think `place()` is better but the reality `place()` has its uses but its not really good for general use.

Comment: I would also note that `pack_propagate(0)` is to be used with `pack()` not `grid()`. The `pack()` and `grid()` methods both have their own logic to manage all aspects of their use.

Comment: Hi Mike. For some reason, when I used grid_propogate(0), it didn't work, but pack_propogate(0) did

Comment: Hi @BryanOakley, the scroll bar doesn't work. I have attached screenshots showing the failure and difference in output in the description. I will update it to further clarify

Comment: I was not saying to use `grid_propigate(0)` I was saying that each geometry manager has different ways of managing layouts. What you need here is to get a better understanding of the geometry managers and use those to manage your widgets. `place()` is only going to add more complications down the road and it really should not be used in this way. `place()` is great for a hand full of needs but other than those you should use `grid()` or `pack()`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because `pack` by default will cause the containing frame to grow or shrink to fit all of the child widgets, but `place` does not. If your frame starts out as 1x1 and you use `place` to add widgets to it, the size will remain 1x1. When you use `place`, it is your responsibility to make the containing widget large enough to contain its children.

This single feature is one of the most compelling reasons to choose `grid` or  `pack` over `place` - these other geometry managers do a lot of work for you so that you can think about the layout logically without getting bogged down in the details of the layout.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I am now having the same issue with .grid. I have updated the question, could you please take the time to review it again?

Comment: @DominicCulyer: I don't see any change to the question. However, if you use `grid_propagate(False)` then you'll have the same problem since you're turning off the ability of `grid` to resize a frame to fit its contents.

Comment: Hi Bryan, I realised its most likely a separate incident and then asked a separate question. It would be great if you could review as I have been stuck on this for days! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74631766/scrollbar-on-canvas-not-scrolling-down-the-canvas