# Scrollbar on canvas not scrolling down the canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, scrollbar

The scrollbar on my canvas does not work when I implement the code in my project, however when I isolate the code, it does work. I have no idea why this could be - potentially a problem with my structure but I do not know what that is.

Here is the logic of my structure

`startup.py` calls `register.py`. `Register.py` calls `accountFrame.py` which calls `GUIFrame.py`. The code for the scrollbar is in `GUIFrame.py`, however the code that populates the data inside the scrollable canvas is in `register.py`

Here is the code for GUIFrame.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter
import mainPage_GUI as mp
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import themes as t
from tkinter import ttk

window=mp.window

#Creates an empty Frame for the GUI
mainFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(window, width=1900, height=980, corner_radius=0)
mainFrame.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
mainFrame.pack_propagate(False)

topFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=mainFrame, width=1865, height=140, corner_radius=10)
topFrame.grid(columnspan=2, padx=15, pady=15)
topFrame.pack_propagate(0)

leftFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=mainFrame, width=380, height=530, corner_radius=10)
leftFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=15, pady=10)
leftFrame.pack_propagate(False)

rightFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=mainFrame, width=1450, height=775, corner_radius=10)
rightFrame.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=15, pady=10, rowspan=2)
rightFrame.pack_propagate(False)

bottomLeftFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(mainFrame, width=380, height=220, corner_radius=10)
bottomLeftFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=15, pady=10)
bottomLeftFrame.pack_propagate(False)


#Creates a scrollbar for the right Frame

#Creates a canvas for the right Frame
canvas2=tk.Canvas(rightFrame, bg="#000000", highlightthickness=0, relief="flat")
canvas2.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

#Creates a scroll bar for the right Frame
scrollbar = customtkinter.CTkScrollbar(master=rightFrame, orientation="vertical", command=canvas2.yview, corner_radius=10)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

#Configures scrollbar to canvas
canvas2.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

#Creates a scrollable frame to place widgets on
scrollableFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(canvas2, fg_color=("#C0C2C5", "#343638"), corner_radius=10)
canvasFrame = canvas2.create_window((0,0), window=scrollableFrame, anchor="nw", tags=("cf"))

#TO DO - resize canvas and to fit all widgets
def handleResize(event):
    c = event.widget
    cFrame = c.nametowidget(c.itemcget("cf", "window"))
    minWidth = cFrame.winfo_reqwidth()
    minHeight = cFrame.winfo_reqheight()
    print (event.width)
    print (event.height)
    if minWidth < event.width:
        c.itemconfigure("cf", width=event.width)
    if minHeight < event.height:
        c.itemconfigure("cf", height=event.height)
    print (event.width)
    print (event.height)
    c.configure(scrollregion=c.bbox("all"))

canvas2.bind('<Configure>', handleResize)

def

 onMousewheel(event):
    canvas2.yview_scroll(-1 * round(event.delta / 120), "units")


canvas2.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", onMousewheel)    
canvas2.bind("<Destroy>", lambda *args, **kwargs: canvas2.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>"))
```

Here is the code for AccountFrame:

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter
import guiFrame as gui
import themes as t

rightFrame=gui.rightFrame
scrollableFrame=gui.scrollableFrame
canvas2 = gui.canvas2

   
#Creates buttons for the Navigation frame
def buttonGeneration():
    navigationLabel = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=gui.leftFrame, text="Navigation Menu:", text_font=t.header2Font, text_color=t.titleColours)
    navigationLabel.pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=10, padx=20, anchor=tk.W)

    loginButton = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=gui.leftFrame, text="Login", width=350, height=45, corner_radius=10, command=loadLogin)
    loginButton.pack(padx=7, pady=5)

    registerButton = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=gui.leftFrame, text="Register", width=350, height=45, corner_radius=10, command=loadRegister)
    registerButton.pack(padx=7, pady=5)



buttonGeneration()
```

Here is the code for Register.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter
import accountFrame as acc
import themes as t

#Create widgets for right frame
def populateRightFrame():
    userRegistrationLabel = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=acc.rightFrame, text="User Registration:", text_font=t.header2Font, text_color=t.titleColours)
    userRegistrationLabel.grid(row=0, sticky="W", padx=20, pady=10)
    
    a = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=acc.scrollableFrame, text="Please enter your email:")
    a.grid(row=1, sticky="W", padx=10, pady=20)
    
    b = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=acc.scrollableFrame, text="Please enter your email:")
    b.grid(row=2, sticky="W", padx=10, pady=20)

    c = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=acc.scrollableFrame, text="Please enter your email:")
    c.grid(row=3, sticky="W", padx=10, pady=20)

    d = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=acc.scrollableFrame, text="Please enter your email:")
    d.grid(row=4, sticky="W", padx=10, pady=20)

    e = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=acc.scrollableFrame, text="Please enter your email:")
    e.grid(row=5, sticky="W", padx=10, pady=20)

    f = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=acc.scrollableFrame, text="Please enter your email:")
    f.grid(row=6, sticky="W", padx=10, pady=20)

    g = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=acc.scrollableFrame, text="Please enter your email:")
    g.grid(row=7, sticky="W", padx=10, pady=20)

    h = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=acc.scrollableFrame, text="Please enter your email:")
    h.grid(row=8, sticky="W", padx=10, pady=20)

    i = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=acc.scrollableFrame, text="Please enter your email:")
    i.grid(row=9, sticky="W", padx=10, pady=20)

    j = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=acc.scrollableFrame, text="Please enter your email:")
    j.grid(row=10, sticky="W", padx=10, pady=20)
    
    k = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=acc.scrollableFrame, text="Please enter your email:")
    k.grid(row=11, sticky="W", padx=10, pady=20)

    l = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=acc.scrollableFrame, text="Please enter your email:")
    l.grid(row=12, sticky="W", padx=10, pady=20)

    m = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=acc.scrollableFrame, text="Please enter your email:")
    m.grid(row=13, sticky="W", padx=10, pady=20)
```

I have tried creating a minimal and reproducible example of this, however it works when I do this!

Please let me know if you need anymore code extracts. I wanted to try keep it to these 3 as I believe the issue lies somewhere here.

Here is a screenshot of what the output looks like vs what is should look like.

[Should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNGnY.png)

[Actually looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8PfM.png)

EDIT - I am happy to send the whole source files to anyone who is interested in solving this if it helps - just let me know your email :)

Update, after further investigation, I have noticed that the function `handleResize()` gets executed twice. When I print `event.width` and `event.height`, I get the following outputs.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRb0C.png)

It is also worth mentioning that my right hand Frame now resizes when `.grid` is used, however it does not when `.place` is used.

[.grid Resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmf09.png)

Comment: It looks like you don't update `scrollregion` after adding the buttons.

Comment: I have verified this with print statements, and the scrollregion does get updated after the buttons. Please view the screenshot added

Comment: Have you verified that it gets updated to the proper value? It looks like you've turned off geometry propagation, so the frame size is not going to grow to hold the widgets.

Comment: Is that not what the handleResize() function does? It should expand the size of the canvas to fit all the widgets?

Comment: Also, when I use .grid rather then .place, for some reason handleResize executes twice? Any idea why this might be? Could it be to do with the parent frames (rightFrame) and window (window)

Comment: I have updated the question again Brian, hopefully this helps your troubleshooting process.

Comment: _"Is that not what the handleResize() function does?"_ - `handleResize` is called when the canvas changes size (ie: if the window is resized). It doesn't do anything with the contents inside the canvas change.

Comment: You need to bind `<Configure>` on `scrollableFrame` and update canvas `scrollregion` inside the callback.

Comment: Are you sure? The handleResize function works completely fine when the code is isolated. It's only when I implement the code with the rest of my project code that the scrollbar stops working

Comment: I have created a new question which makes the question more specific. Please find it here - any help appreciated! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74643601/main-tkinter-window-stops-scrollbar-from-working